# How to use fancybox in Codeigniter(last version) view

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, fancybox

I want to use fancybox in one of my CodeIgniter View. First of all, I downloaded fancybox then I Unzip and copy files in `application/third_party` folder of CodeIgniter. Then in myView.php I did this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('third_party/fancyBox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js'); ?>"></script>
```

but when I use Firefox ( Inspect Element) to see all the request, I got 404 error(of `mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js`). What I'm wrong? Which approach should I follow?

Update:

This is the view part that I'm trying right now:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css"></script>
  <script src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('/Fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js'); ?>"></script>

   <title>Private Area</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('home_view_style.css');?>"> 
 </head>
 <body>
   <h4>Benvenuto Utente</h4>
   <a href="home/logout">Logout</a>
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" rel="group" href="http://www.istruzioneformazionelavoro.it/Engine/RAServeFile.php/f/corsi/84/Tabella_corsi_allegatoDD311.pdf">prova</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put it inside application folder, create folder where is your index.php, f.e. assets, extract fancy box there and then inside your view write something like `<script src="/asssets/fancyBox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>`

Aha, the approach - you can extract codeigniter files where your webroot is and it's fine, but as user guide speaks, you can make public folder and put your index.php there, set your domain to point this folder and adjust application and system path inside your index.php. Then, you files are safe outside public sight.

Learn by viewing others people work. I've taken a look at github, recent CI project, there you can clearly see directory structure, where assets are https://github.com/PandaGG/CI_Blog , the index.php file is  inside public dir.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I correct as you told me and now the request is working fine. But, What I want to do is like this http://jsfiddle.net/RHaAX/. I put in my view the same code(of course an other href) but it doesn't work. I still don't get why.

Comment: See jsfiddle's result frame source and just copy or show us your view

Comment: I just attached the part of view where I'm working on.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8fvmcB94 - something like this? also notice the paths and html5 doctype. Check where your mousewheel js is. Pure html.

Comment: I have no problem with the request, but when I click on "prova" I always open an other tab.

Comment: maybe your browser doesnt support data atribute, try simple with `$(".open_ajax").fancybox({type: 'iframe'}); ` Just add class open_ajax to your link

Comment: I don't get what you say, I have to do something like this ? `<a class="fancybox" class="open-ajax"..... ` Then? where should I put this `$(".open_ajax").fancybox({type: 'iframe'});`?

Comment: create standalone js script between <script></script>, you can put .fancybox instead .open_ajax. Put it at the end of the body. This question gets too wide, ask new one.